# Copy the last column for the upcoming rows

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

FILE:

```
900 1 37
900 2 41
900 3 278
918 1 9999
918 2 9999
918 3 9999
```

And I want to obtain a new file which looks like this:

```
918 1 37
918 2 41
918 3 278
```

I want to take the last column from the previous set of numbers (900) and use it for the last column of the next set (918).

The values that I want to replace are always 9999. Basically I want to replace everything that is 9999 with the last "valid" value (ex. when I have something different than 9999).

Comment: Are there only two different numbers in the first column?

Comment: No. In reality I have a bigger file with numbers on the first column from 0 to around 40 000. But I have the values that I am interested in only at "round" numbers (0,100,200,...900, etc) on the last column and I want to use those for the next numbers where I have 9999 on the last column.

Comment: Does the 3rd line have a typo? Should column 2 have the value 3? Can column 2 be used as a key?

Comment: @glennjackman I believe only the last column should be replaced by the data from the lines above.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I had a typo. I corrected the question.

Comment: Indeed, only the last column should be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue.

```
perl -lane 'if ($prev == $F[0])
            {push @buff, $F[2]}
            elsif ($F[2] == 9999)
            {print join " ", @F[0,1], shift @buff}
            else {$prev = $F[0]; @buff = $F[2]}
           ' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line;
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output;
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array;
- We keep a `@buff`er that remembers the column 3 for the last number in column 1, remembered in `$prev`. If the number in column 1 is the same as on the previous line, we add the last column into the buffer;
- If the last number is 9999, we print the value of the first two columns, but use the buffer for the last column;
- Otherwise, a new section has started. We reinitialize the buffer and reset $prev.

A bit shorter version:

```
perl -lane 'if($F[2]==9999){print join" ",@F[0,1],shift@buff}else{@buff=()if$prev!=$F[0];push@buff,$F[2];$prev=$F[0]}' -- file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$3==9999{$3=p[$2]; print} {p[$2]=$3}' file
918 1 37
918 2 41
918 3 278
```